# $f$ irreducible and $\pi(V(f,g))$ dense implies $V(f)=V(f,g)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a field and $T^n:=(K^*)^n$ be the algebraic torus. Consider $f,g\in K[x_1^{\pm 1},\ldots,x_n^{\pm 1}]$ and let $\pi:T^n\to T^{n-1}$ be the projection onto the first $n-1$ coordinates. Assume that $f$ is irreducible and that $\pi(V(f,g))$ is dense in $T^{n-1}$. Does this imply $V(f)=V(f,g)$?

My thoughts:
It is really the left inclusion I'm asking for, as the other is trivial. Thus we know that $\pi(V(f,g)) \subseteq \pi(V(f))$. Furthermore, the irreducibility of $f$ implies that $V(f)$ has dimension $n-1$ so we must have $\text{dim}\big(\pi(V(f))\big) \leq n-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does (assuming $f\neq 0$). If the projection of $V(f,g)$ is dense in $T^{n-1}$, then $V(f,g)$ must have dimension at least $n-1$. As $V(f)$ is irreducible because $f$ is irreducible and has dimension $n-1$ by Krull's height theorem, we may use the fact that all proper closed subspaces of an irreducible topological space have strictly smaller dimension to conclude that $V(f)=V(f,g)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have one follow up question, which might be trivial, but how does the projection of $V(f,g)$ being dense imply $\text{dim}(V(f,g))\geq n-1$?

Comment: Depends on your level of technology, but here's one way: given a dominant map of varieties $f:X\to Y$, we get an induced morphism on function fields $k(Y)\to k(X)$ which shows that $\dim X\geq \dim Y$. Now apply this as $X$ runs over the irreducible components of $V(f,g)$ with $Y=\overline{f(X)}$ - as closure commutes with finite unions, some $\overline{f(X)}=T^{n-1}$, giving that $V(f,g)$ has an irreducible component of dimension $\geq n-1$ and therefore $V(f,g)$ is of dimension $\geq n-1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!